# Can't get the right PortNumber type in the connectionOptions data type (coServers)

Tags: haskell, rabbitmq, amqp

So I am using the Network.AMQP library in Haskell and I am trying to connect to a broker via the openConnection'' function which requires a ConnectionOpts structure which itself takes a list of tuples of Strings and PortNumbers in the coServers field. I wanted to make this in a seperate function which takes a String (the host name) and a PortNumber. So far so good. But when i try to insert those parameters in the coServers field then I get the error like this:

Couldn't match expected type `network-2.6.2.1:Network.Socket.Types.PortNumber' with actual type`PortNumber'
In the expression: port
In the expression: (host, port)
In the `coServers' field of a record

here is a snippet that reproduces the error (not my actual program but this one runs into the exact same problem and is much shorter.)

```
import Network
import Network.AMQP


main :: IO()
main = do
  publisher1 "127.0.0.1" 5555


publisher1 :: String -> PortNumber -> IO ()
publisher1 host port = do
  conn <- openConnection'' defaultConnectionOpts {coServers = [(host, port)] , coHeartbeatDelay = Just 30}
  chn <- openChannel conn
  return ()
```

so after I tried some other PortNumber types I know and I can actually import  (i.e. Network.Socket, Network.Socket.Internal ...) and after I looked at the library source code , I tried to find out  where this "special" PortNumber is comming from (I know, eventually it is coming from Network.Socket.Type as the error message suggests but the Network.AMQP isn't importing this one either). So I cloned the repository and tried to compile it and well, it worked, as suspected. I commented out the imported Network library (the one that's named Network) and then I became the error message that the Type PortNumber is not in scope. Also as to be expected.

So it should work with the Network library ,but why is my program not getting the "right" type (or to be precise why do I get this type inferred from ghc?)

My problem is not that i can't get it working. I can circumvent this problem  when I change the type of the function to String -> Integer -> IO() and add the line

let goodPort = fromInteger port

and change the port parameter in coservers to goodPort it works.

But I really , REALLY want to know why this is happening and how I can solve this problem more elegantly.

Comment: Your snippet does not reproduce the error for me. It loads and runs. This is on ghci 7.10.2, from stack resolver lts-3.10, which gives me amqp 0.13.0 and network 2.6.2.1.